# substitute the number after decimal with 0

Tags: c#, string-formatting

How do I replace the decimal part of currency with 0's
Here's my cuurency:  166.7
This is to be formatted as  000000016670

The length of this field is 12.

`s.padright(12,0);` This is will the second  part I believe.
The first part will involve replace the number after the decimal with 000..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply by 100 then format the number.

```
var num = 166.7;
var numString = (num * 100).ToString("000000000000");
```

Multiplying by 100 turns 166.7 to 16670. Next you need to pad the left part of the number, which is what the ToString does. Each 0 represents a digit. It means, write the number that belongs to that digit, and if no number is present print 0.

Comment: It looks like this might need a little more explanation, as I'm reading the question as the "currency" being a string from the outset. I might be wrong.

Comment: @spender - Might be. Although I interpreted that it was a "currency" as it being a numeric field.

Comment: It's not the best question in the world, is it? It would be difficult to PadRight a number.

Comment: Yes, it is a decimal field.. I am converting it to string. String.format(s,"{0:f2}); This is my default formatting though

Comment: @user575219 - This should work for you then. In the code above, num is a decimal and numString is a string.

Comment: is there a way to set this format in sql server. This is what I mean String.Format(dr.format, values); dr.format comes from the database.. values is the string/currency we are trying to format.

Comment: @user575219 - Do you mean you want the SQL code to do the formatting?